# Is it possible to make a session-specific SIgnalR connection?

Tags: .net, signalr

Let us suppose that I am implementing a visitor counter with SignalR. A static variable is incremented whenever a new visitor arrives and is decremented whenever a visitor left the building. I wonder whether a connection be session-specific, so I can increment the counter whenever a new session was created and decrement it whenever a session is no longer connected.

This would mean that whenever a user successfully logs in or opens the first tab in a browser when already logged in, the counter should be incremented and whenever the last such tab in a browser is closed, the counter should be decremented. I can do it as follows:

- On server I store all the sessions having an alive connection
- Whenever such a tab is opened, a server method is invoked, which will check whether the current session is in the storage, if so, increments the tab count
- Whenever such a tab is closed, a server method is invoked, which will decrement the tab count and if 0, then removes the session from the storage
- Whenever a connection is lost (for example, browser is closed, internet connection was lost) the session is removed from the storage

I wonder whether this is possible with SignalR out of the box, so that SignalR would track connections to a sessionid. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you are using `Hub` classes, you can do this by using server side events and corresponding handlers, such as `OnConnected`, and `OnDisconnected`.

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        //this is called after connection is started.
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        //called when the connection is disconnected.
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }
}
```

For more information, please check [How to handle connection lifetime events in the Hub class](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#connectionlifetime).

**Update:** Whenever a new connection will be made, `OnConnected` will be called automatically by SignalR framework. There you can increase your static variable and what not. And in `OnDisconnected`, you can decrease the variable that is called whenever a connection is destroyed/stopped.

Other than this, you can also persist [User](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#database), [Group](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups#storedatabase), and Connection information, in external memory like SQL Server, and track it explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I was mixing up the question.

Comment: Can you elaborate the idea?